# Collection View Search Bar Disappear in header after pop from navigation view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I have added a search bar (which in a search display controller) in a uicollectionview header.
After click a cell and push to another view controller by navigation controller, and then pop and goes back to the view controller with uicollection view. The search bar will be disappeared. But it does exist there, you could active the search by clicking the empty area which the search bar should be located. (i.e. header area of the uicollectionview)

It only happen if the search bar is not on the screen when you click the cell.

I create the app by code only. I haven't use IB or storyboard.

hope someone could give me advice on it.

Many thanks.

---

Edited on 6 / 10 / 2014

I don't remember my exact solution, However, if you encounter similar problem, you could try this.

1. Set the **UIScrollViewDelegate** to the ViewController
2. Add this delegate method

> ```
> - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
> {
>     if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= _searchVC.searchBar.frame.size.height / 2) {
>         [scrollView setContentOffset:(CGPoint){0, 0} animated:YES];
>     } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < _searchVC.searchBar.frame.size.height) {
>         [scrollView setContentOffset:(CGPoint){0, _searchVC.searchBar.frame.size.height} animated:YES];
>     }
> }
> ```

The above code control the content offset to show/hide the search bar. Therefore the search bar would be fully showed or fully hide.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm also facing this problem!

Comment: Did you try setNeedsDisplay on the searchBar in your viewDidAppear? UICollectionViews are known to give a lot of problems.